# Intersections between n points

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a formula for the maximum amount of intersections caused by connecting n points? I get that there are multiple results for number of intersections between n points depending on how the points are placed. Is there like an added factor that compensates for that factor?

Comment: is the graph simple, complete ,  a digraph ? those could affect the answer a bit in my eyes ( very limited knowledge admittedly).

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270937/how-can-you-construct-as-many-intersections-as-possible-with-n-lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume this is in the plane, with no three points collinear (otherwise with three collinear points you could say there are infinitely many intersections), 
and you're talking about the intersections (other than the points themselves) of the line segments joining the points.

Consider first the case $n=4$.  If one of the points is inside the convex hull of the other three, there are no intersections.  Otherwise, there is one.

Now for the general case with $n$ vertices.  If the points are in "general position", no points are the intersection of more than two lines, and there is a one-to-one map from the intersections to unordered $4$-tuples of points, taking each intersection to the endpoints of the lines that intersect there.  If none of the points is in the convex hull of the others (e.g. if the points are all on a circle), this map is also onto.  Thus the maximum number of intersections is $n \choose 4$.